# Math.ceil() method is not working with double values

Tags: java, android

I want to roundoff the values of double variable to the next positive whole number irrespective of the what i get after the decimal point. So i searched about it and found Math.ceil() method do this work but when i am using it in my code it is not giving the next positive whole number.

Please help me as i already know we need to provide double values and i am providing all the double values only but still its working like roundoff function.

Below is My Code :-

```
completedorders = Double.parseDouble(totalcompletedorders);

Log.i("COMPLETED ORDERS" , String.valueOf(completedorders));

double l = Math.ceil(completedorders / 5.0);

Log.i("Value of L", String.valueOf(l));
```

When i am logging the values in the Logcat  i am getting these values.

```
05-28 16:16:48.125 26657-26657/com.example.example I/COMPLETED ORDERS: 7.0
05-28 16:16:48.125 26657-26657/com.example.example I/Value of L: 1
```

Comment: Try to do the calculation outside the `ceil` function or (completedorders / 5.0)

Comment: Are you sure the version of the code deployed matches that source?

Comment: @Thilo yes sir.

Comment: @mooga I tried that aswell sir i took the value of completedorders/5.0 into a another double variable i and then passed i inside the Math.ceil(i) but still i am getting same values

Comment: have you tried to log it directly without assign it to variable ?

Comment: Why does it print `1` and not `1.0` ? It also prints `7.0`. Is that really the code that creates this log? According to Javadoc, String#valueOf(double) should print at least one decimal digit.

Comment: are you sure your code is `String.valueOf(l)` and not `String.valueOf(1)` ?

Comment: Print and share following , `totalcompletedorders` , `completedorders`

Comment: Thank you guys for your valuable time and inputs it was my mistake the code is absolutely fine but the thing is there was some issue with android studio it was executing my previous code in background which had math.round method....now i have cleaned the project and uninstalled and reinstalled the app ...now its working fine as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code is absolutely fine but the thing is there was some issue with android studio it was executing my previous code in background which had math.round method....now i have cleaned the project and uninstalled and reinstalled the app ...now its working fine as intended.